# Providing a Class object with upper type bound using classManifest

Tags: scala, generics, manifest, type-erasure

Let's say I need to provide a method with a `java.lang.Class` object that represents a subclass of some parent class `A`. I need to do this from another method that has a generic parameter with an upper type bound to `A`.

I thought this might work:

```scala
class A
def f(clazz: java.lang.Class[_ <: A]) = ()
def g[T <: A : Manifest] = f(classManifest[T].erasure)
```

But it does not:

```
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.Class[_$1(in method g)] where type _$1(in method g)
 required: java.lang.Class[_ <: A]
         def g[T <: A : Manifest] = f(classManifest[T].erasure)
                                                       ^
```

Why can't the compiler figure out that `T` is, indeed, a subclass of `A`? Is there anyway I can help it? Or should I approach this in a completely different manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because [`erasure` has the type `Class[_]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/ClassManifest.html), which is an existential type. This means that `Class` object `erasure` is parametrized by some type, but it is not important which exact type this is. The `erasure` does not have a type `Class[T]` above.

The method `f` expects a parameter of type `Class[_ <: A]` which is some type known to be a subtype of `A`. This upper bound is not necessarily ensured by the `Class[_]` type above.

**Solution**: you know that the `erasure` has a proper type, it's just that this type is not exposed in the `ClassManifest` object. Simply cast it:

```
classManifest[T].erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[A]]
```

EDIT:

If you have a subclass `B` of `A`:

```
scala> class A

scala> def f(clazz: java.lang.Class[_ <: A]) = ()

scala> def g[T <: A : Manifest] = f(classManifest[T].erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[A]])

scala> g[A]

scala> class B extends A

scala> g[B]
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, as your explanation is both correct and clear. Your solution, however, does not work for me because my real world `f` method really needs to have the `Class` object for the subtype, not for `A`. My own solution was to give up doing this with generics and pass the class object (obtained with `classOf`) all along the call path, i.e., a call to `g` now looks like: `g[SomeSubclass](classOf[SomeSubclass])`. (The type parameter is still needed for reasons not shown above.)

Comment: You are completely right. I was confused and had not realized that even if you cast the `Class` object for `B` as an instance of `Class[A]`, it _remains_ a `Class` object for `B`. Thank you!